# Problem with apt-get update coupled with docker and nvidia docker

Tags: apt, nvidia, updates, docker

I am struggling to install docker on Ubuntu 18.05 bionic.

I have just started to work on a shared machine and I am not perfectly aware of what was done before.

Anyway, I deleted all previous version of docker and when I try to do a `sudo apt-get update`

I get the following error:

```
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu18.04/amd64  Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu18.04/amd64  Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
```

I have already spent quiet a long time trying to fix the issue without any success. I would be happy if someone could help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: You can try by removing your docker repository file and list, it has worked in my case : --->  
from : "/etc/apt/sources.list.d" and "/etc/apt/sources.list"